# TypeError in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the code for [this SaaS example](http://memcachedasaservice.com/), but when I run the code on Ruby 1.9.3 and signup, I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCB0H.png

I'm on `Ruby 1.9.3`, `Rails 3.2.13`

It seems to be failing on the creation step:

users_controller.rb:

```
    def create_memcached_instance
    docker_path = '/usr/bin'
    container_id = `#{docker_path}docker run -d -p 11211 jbarbier/memcached memcached -u daemon`
    cmd = "#{docker_path}docker inspect #{container_id}"
    json_infos = `#{cmd}`
    i = JSON.parse(json_infos)
    @user.memcached = i["NetworkSettings"]["PortMapping"]["11211"]
    @user.container_id = container_id
    @user.docker_ip = i["NetworkSettings"]["IpAddress"]
  end
```

Full Trace:

```
json (1.7.7) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.7.7) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.7.7) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `create_memcached_instance'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:49:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1753984858439435449__process_action__4397313512021220537__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1573725910118489674__call__8700384058904149__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Dogbert I can't paste more then 2 links, so I figured you'd see the GitHub link on the first link. https://github.com/jbarbier/SaaS_Memcached/

Comment: Can you paste the *code* and perhaps the entire stacktrace (error).

Comment: Yes paste the portion of code you are having trouble with so people can assist you with precision.

Comment: some of your interpolated strings have nil, which you try to convert to string

Comment: try to log every variable you are using, so you could see which of it is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > j = JSON.parse(nil)
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
    from /Users/mike.campbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
    from /Users/mike.campbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
    from /Users/mike.campbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

That quick IRB experiement leads me to the conclusion that your variable `json_infos` is `nil`.

Are you sure you don't want `docker_path = '/usr/bin/'` (with the trailing slash)? Unless you have the directory `/usr/bindocker` ...

Comment: Er, I fixed the path, but how would I fix it?

Comment: Code: `json_infos = `#{cmd}`
    i = JSON.parse(json_infos)`

Comment: I've no idea what you mean, did you add the `/` to `docker_path`? like I said, `json_infos = '#{cmd}'` is returning `nil`, up to you to work out why, no one can help you with that.

Comment: Yeah, and it isn't working... I've got no idea how to fix it :\

Comment: use `raise` and other ways of inspecting variables. find out what `cmd` is by putting `raise cmd.inspect` after the line that assigns that variable. Then run that shell command in the environment that this script runs in, and see what the output is... etc etc.

Comment: Also, the github page says: _Remember to replace jbarbier/memcached with the name of your image._. Looks like you didn't do this.

Comment: Wait, stop! It fixed it! YAY! :P

Comment: I was using the default image, that does work. The trailing slash did fix it on a clean ubuntu install.

Comment: nice one. the done thing now is to tick the answer that helped you solve your problem.